# Include path PHP warning on Ubuntu with Slim app

Tags: php, apache, slim, lamp

I'm having an issue with include paths in a Slim app on apache/ubuntu with PHP 7. When my app/routes index page tries to include a file located in a subdirectory, I get the following in my apache error.log, but the path seems correct to me:

```
PHP Warning:  include(myapp/production/include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 33
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'myapp/production/include.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 33
```

The directory structure is:

```
/var/www/html/
├── index.php
├── myapp/
│   ├── vendor/
│   └── production/
│       └── include.php
```

relevant line 33 in index.php:

```
include ('myapp/production/include.php');
```

Could there be something related to file/directory permissions that is causing this? I'm fairly knew to setting up web apps on linux servers; any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**:

I added a test include file in the main web directory (same as index.php), and that include does work.

Comment: Yes you should check permissions, and even for debug sake I'd create `test.php` file in the same folder as `index.php` and try to `include` it, then you'll figure out if it's about permissions or not

Comment: I tried a test include in the web root, and it does work.

Comment: Then either the path is wrong or some permissions are missing

Comment: Please provide the exact code in test.php and in index.php that you think should include this `include.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to guess, I suspect that the case of the directory and file name is different on disk to what you are using in your PHP code.

Linux has a case sensitive file system, so a directory called `Production` is different to one called `production`.

Ensure that the text you use in your `include` statement exactly matches the names of the directories and files that are on the disk.